# I am not getting npm version in windows after nodejs installation ,instead getting this issue

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

`'CALL "C:\Program Files\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\Program Files\nodejs\\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" prefix -g'` is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Please check if you have the node directory in the PATH variable in system env.settings

Comment: Yes path is there. C:\Program Files\nodejs\;

Comment: This is not an answer to the question, it's a comment.

Comment: sorry about that, will keep an eye next time. 
If you navigate to the node directory, open the console and try that command stripped of the node path like
     node.exe "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js"